# Profile picture upload, then disappear

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture

I upload my profile picture about 5-6 times but everytime, after refreshing my profile page, the picture disappears from my profile and come back the last one I used.

The image is just 500 kB and no report pop up.

Comment: Did you click *Save profile* at the bottom?

Comment: Yep i saved my profile. Probably users need reputation to upload profile picture?

Comment: No, you can pick a profile image the moment you join. There is no minimum reputation requirement.

Comment: Save profile buttons are low in the page and the fact that the image updates immediately doesn't clue the user in that the change isn't permanent until you (find) and click the save button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no record that you ever changed your profile image since you joined.

Make sure you click on the *Save* button at the bottom of the form after you changed your profile image.

Comment: I'm sorry! I'm so noob here but... that button was "invisible" for me! 
(IMHO, it's placed too low, IMHO).